# iOS - fix UIImageView aspect ratio in static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

There is only one `UIImageView` in the static `UITableViewCell`

I want to fix the following things:

1. `UIImageView`'s width equals to `UITableViewCell`'s width
2. `UIImageView`'s aspect ratio equals to `16:9`
3. `UIImageView`'s bottom to `UITableViewCell`'s bottom is `48`

Since in every device, the screen width is fixed and the `UITableViewCell`'s width equals to screen's width. I expect that if I set the `UIImageView` leading and trailing space to the `UITableViewCell`, the width of it can be known and therefore its height, according to the ratio constraint. But the height is broken because the system somehow reads the setting of cell's row height first and then render the image height according to the `48` constraint, regardless of the ratio constraint.

Expected:

[image]

Runtime:

[image]

My constraints:

[image]

Any answers are appreciated! Better explain about what is the drawing order in such a situation. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a fixed size for the cells?

Comment: Check out this video on youtube, probably works for you [https://youtu.be/hEJEru-Ipn4?t=4m57s](https://youtu.be/hEJEru-Ipn4?t=4m57s)

Comment: @Jelly But I have tried `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` as well and not work.

Comment: Do you get any autolayout errors in console?